# Kendo Datepickers not working with dynamic Angular table

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

AngularJS Table with Kendo Autocomplete. I used the Kendo autocomplete input to select a resource from my database and Angular to actually add that resource to the table.

When the resource is added, there are columns to assign them a start and end dates that use the Kendo datepicker. For some reason, these datepickers aren't working. At first, it didn't even render like a Kendo datepicker until I added "data-role="datepicker" to the input. Now, it renders like a datepicker but the Calendar doesn't drop down like it should, so I can't actually select a date.

If I use the browser console to manually call the datepicker, it duplicates the calendar icon and the monthpicker will then work. This means I can't just have it call the datepicker every time a resource is added or it will duplicate all the other datepickers that are already there.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><a class="table-sort" href="" ng-click="orderByField='name'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Name</a></th>
        <th>Start</th>
        <th>End</th>
        <th>Allocation</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="resource in resources | filter:Filter | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>{{resource.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="datepicker-wrap">
                <input id="start-{{$index}}" value="" kendo-date-picker type="text" class="datepicker" required
                       data-role="datepicker" role="combobox"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="datepicker-wrap">
                <input id="end-{{$index}}" value="" kendo-date-picker type="text" class="datepicker" required
                       data-role="datepicker" role="combobox"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-field" style="float: left; min-width: 200px; margin-right:10px;">
                <input type="text" required>
                <span class="highlight"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-wrap">
                <input type="checkbox" id='checkbox-{{$index}}' name='check-group' ng-model="entity.isChecked"
                       ng-change="selectEntity()"/>
                <label for="checkbox-{{$index}}" style="margin:0;"><span>Billable</span></label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="delete-row" ng-click="removeRow(resource.name)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="add-resource clearfix">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="autocomplete-wrap">
            <input id="Searchlist" placeholder="Resource Name" type="text" name="name" class="autocomplete"
                   ng-model="newresource.name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position: relative; bottom: 17px; margin-left: 15px;">
        <button class="btn btn-action" ng-click="addresource()" ng-disabled="newresource.verificaDadosresource()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Resource
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
function ResourceController($scope) {
    $scope.resources = listresources();
    $scope.newresource = new resource({});
    $scope.newresource.name = '';

    $scope.addresource = function () {
        $scope.resources.push($scope.newresource);
        $scope.newresource = new resource({});
        $scope.newresource.name = '';
    }
    $scope.clearAll = function (resources) {
        var length = resources.length;
        resources.splice(0, length);
    }

    $scope.removeRow = function (name) {
        var index = -1;
        var comArr = eval($scope.resources);
        for (var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++) {
            if (comArr[i].name === name) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index === -1) {
            alert("Something gone wrong");
        }
        $scope.resources.splice(index, 1);
    };
}

function listresources() {
    var list = [];

    return list;
}

function resource(args) {
    this.name = args.name || undefined;

    this.verificaDadosresource = function () {
        return this.name.length < 1;
    }

    this.verificanameresource = function () {
        return this.name.length < 1;
    }
}
</script>
```

Calling Kendo Datepicker

```
$(".datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    change: kendoDateChange
});

$("#monthpicker").kendoDatePicker({
    // defines the start view
    start: "year",

    // defines when the calendar should return date
    depth: "year",

    // display month and year in the input
    format: "MMMM yyyy"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.

I needed a dependency for kendo.directives in order to use their widgets with angular.

```
var app = angular.module("your-angular-app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction